# Indy snmp with freepascal

Tags: snmp, indy, freepascal

I'm making a simple snmp application on raspberry pi use indy with freepascal. 
I can ping to device and send get/set request via mibbrowser but this doesn't work, send query always fail.

```
program snmptest;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE DELPHI}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  sysutils, IdSNMP, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient;

var
  snmp:tidsnmp;
  s,mib:string;
begin
  mib:='1.3.6.1.4.1.6247.32.1.2.12.0';
  snmp:=tidsnmp.create(nil);
  try
    snmp.host:='172.16.1.222';
    snmp.community:='public';
    snmp.query.clear;
    snmp.query.pdutype:=pdugetrequest;
    snmp.query.mibadd(mib,'');
    if snmp.sendquery then
    begin
      s:=snmp.reply.mibget(mib);
      writeln(s);
    end
    else begin
      writeln('fail!');
    end;
  finally
    snmp.free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code (though you should paste it directly into the question instead of linking it). Can you also share the output of running the program?

Comment: There's only "failed", nothing more. FPC v2.6.0.

Comment: `TIdSNMP.SendQuery()` returns false if it times out waiting for the reply to arrive (the default `TIdSNMP.ReceiveTimeout` is 5 seconds), or if it cannot parse the reply. Without seeing the actual network traffic, there is no way for us to diagnose this problem. You will have to step into Indy's source code yourself and see what is really happening. What is the value of `TIdSNMP.Reply.ErrorStatus` after `SendQuery()` exits? Have you tried using a packet sniffer to compare TIdSNMP's traffic with MibBrowser's traffic?

Comment: ErrorStatus=2 no such name. And wireshark: [link](http://i.imgur.com/mhxFTAb.png)

Comment: Well, then it's pretty clear-cut. NoSuchName means the SNMP Agent does not have that OID. You need to find out which OIDs the agent actually support. I suggest using an SNMPwalk command (net-snmp) or a MIB browser to find the correct OID.

Comment: They're exactly the same. I did copy from mib browser. But in wireshark it only shows '1.3.6', I don't get it.

Comment: And I've just tried net-snmp command, it works fine.